# How to align Logo Image and Menu items in one line without using position absolute?

Tags: html, css

**Background:** The current design that I am working on, requires a logo followed by menu in one line. What I want is that the logo and the menu (which consist of two parts which are two unordered list here) to appear in one row or as one section.

**Parts of the header:** The header consist of Logo Image, menu left and menu right. The menu left and menu right are unordered list items in code.

**Problem faced:** I am trying to add the logo image and menus in one div element to bring them together in one line. But the image is appearing on top and followed by the menu element. I have tried using the display:inline to bring the logo image on one side and menu starting after the logo image but it didnot work.I am sharing my code. Can the image be positioned and aligned along with the menu items without using position absolute? There is only HTML5 and CSS3 in the code. There is no javascript in the code.

```css
.header{
 position:relative;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}


.top{
 height:20%;
 border:1px solid #000;
}

.logo{
 height:100%;
 display:inline;
}
.element{
 clear:both;
 border:1px solid #000;
 float:left;
}
.leftc{
 display:inline;
}
.leftc li{
 list-style:none;
 display:inline-block;
}

.rightc{
 display:inline;
}
.rightc li{
 list-style:none;
 display:inline-block;
 
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
 </head>
 <body>
  <header class="header">
   <div class="top">
    <div class="log">
     <img src="http://thegamecorner.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/playstation-blue-background-logo-1920x1080-1.jpg" alt="logo" class="logo"/>
    </div>
    <div class="element">
     <ul class="leftc">
      <li><a href="index.html">Buy</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html">Rent</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html">Sell</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html">Mortgages</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html">Agent finder</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html">More</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
     <ul class="rightc">
      <li><a href="#">List your rental</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Advertise</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sign in</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Join</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  
  </header>
 
 
 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If it is possible to avoid the unordered list, I would suggest you to take a look at flexbox to solve this problem. A quick search on google will give you guides like [this one](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) which I found very useful.

Comment: at the time of asking the question I had not read about the flexbox...I now know flexbox and use it to make menus...thanks

Answer (score 1):

Explanation in comments of CSS where the changes are made.

1. Give height to header
2. Making height of top to 100% as it to cover the whole header height can be adjusted accordingly.
3. Properties to be added to div with class **log**

   ```
   .top>.log{
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   width: 200px;
   display: inline;
   float: left;
   }
   ```

```css
.header{
 position:relative;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
    height:30vh;/*giving height to header*/
}


.top{
 height:100%;/*making it to cover complete header*/
 border:1px solid #000;
}

.logo{
 height:100%;
 display:inline;
 
}
/* properties to be added to log div*/
.top>.log{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    width: 200px;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
.element{
    /*removing the clear property*/
 border:1px solid #000;
 float:left;
}
.leftc{
 display:inline;
}
.leftc li{
 list-style:none;
 display:inline-block;
}

.rightc{
 display:inline;
}
.rightc li{
 list-style:none;
 display:inline-block;
 
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
 </head>
 <body>
  <header class="header">
   <div class="top">
    <div class="log">
     <img src="http://thegamecorner.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/playstation-blue-background-logo-1920x1080-1.jpg" alt="logo" class="logo"/>
    </div>
    <div class="element">
     <ul class="leftc">
      <li><a href="index.html">Buy</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html">Rent</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html">Sell</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html">Mortgages</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html">Agent finder</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html">More</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
     <ul class="rightc">
      <li><a href="#">List your rental</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Advertise</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sign in</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Join</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  
  </header>
 
 
 
 </body>
</html>
```